# How to spy on things brought in with require() in jasmine? or "import * as foo from 'place' "

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, jasmine

I am trying to test a library I import and use: detectrtc, and I am unable to return a mock object for the jasmine Spy. Every attempt to spy and mock pulls through the actual information, not the fake info.

I was initially importing detectrtc using:

`import * as DetectRTC from 'detectrtc';`

Then using it inside a function like:

`const os: string = DetectRTC.osName;`

but since this will do the import on the component load i figured i'd always be too late to spyOn it when testing the function it is used in.

So I switched to grabbing the library inside the function in question using require() to make the testing easier/possible:

`const detectRTC = require('detectrtc');`

`const os: string = detectRTC.osName;`

Both of these approaches work in the actual program, I should add. But how do I spyOn and return some fake values?

I've found this https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1414 which suggests it may be a jasmine bug but I'm not sure I'm right in that assessment as that could be a different case.

I think the problem is focussed on `require()` and the fact it doesn't fit the `spyOn(object, 'function')` syntax but i'm not sure.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please share your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  There are many reasons the spy may not be working.  Refactoring to use [Dependency Injection](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) might help, but can be challenging with 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a solution to this. The problem was that detectrtc was being imported as an object, and other ones that are easier to test are more of a list of functions. So i wrapped detectrtc in a getter and mocked that, rather than detectrtc itself:

```
import * as DetectRTC from 'detectrtc'; 
getDetectRTC(): any {
    return DetectRTC;
}
```

Then I spied on that function like so:

```
const detectRTCspy = spyOn(component, 'getDetectRTC').and.returnValue(mockDetectRTC);
```

Having declared the mock object I wanted to return.

Hopefully this is helpful for anyone who stumbles across this.